# Visualforce Button open a new section

Tags: apex, visualforce

I would ask a help with PageBlockSection, I have a Visualforce where the User can attach photos, I would have to click a button which would appear where a second PageBlockSection has another inputField to insert another picture. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to upload multiple attachments in one go, or have a way to add another after uploading the first?

Comment: In my Visualforce I have for example 5 pageblocks and in each I have a inputfile, but I would like it to appear only the first and add more if they want some picture he clicks a button to appear where the second section. Got it?

Comment: i am using a button what open a new section but i have this error: apex:inputFile can not be used in conjunction with an action component, apex:commandButton or apex:commandLink that specifies a rerender or oncomplete attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the rendered attribute to control whether a section or field is visible, so when he has finished attaching the first picture and clicks attach more, the controller in the background sets a variable which controls the rendering of the second section and displays it (you will also need a reRender attribute on button click to tell it which sections to rerender when the button is clicked).
Also I would think rather than 5 actual sections, you could have five sectionItems of input fields where you put in the picture files. 5 sections would be too spaced out ? unless that is how you want to do it.

Here's a great post from @bob buzzard explaining how you can do this
http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html